# Problems with Silverlight Toolkit in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've added Silverlight toolkit into my WP7 app.

```
<Button Content="Country">
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="England" Tag="1" Click="set_country" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Germany" Tag="2" Click="set_country" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="France" Tag="3" Click="set_country" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Spain" Tag="4" Click="set_country" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Italy" Tag="5" Click="set_country" />
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Handler:

```
private void set_country(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    var tag = menuItem.Tag.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(tag);
}
```

But it's the problem in this string in MainPage.g.i.cs:

```
this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
```

Mistake: Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.MenuItem.Click'. [Line: 31 Position: 72]

Comment: Please don't swear. I don't know the wp7 toolkit but are you right about the mouseeventargs? Should'nt it be RoutedEventargs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler signature is wrong:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    MessageBox.Show("You chose to  " + menuItem.Header.ToString(),"Result",MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```